# In starting my page templates in Django are visible but, then some of pages are not visible and new pages are also not visible

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I made pages in Django in starting (about us, contact us, blogs, home) and then shop page. After all this my some of previous pages (about us, contact us, blogs) are not visible/displaying now, also now if i am creating any new page it also not displaying.
Even all the things (views, urls) are configured correctly.
[previous page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKZ0O.png)
[previous page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fJJI.png)
[shop page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igLKW.png)
[new page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHk09.png)

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static%}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/contact_us.css">

<section>
    
    <div class="section-header">
      
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      
        <div class="contact-info">
          <div class="contact-info-item">
            <div class="contact-info-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            
            <div class="contact-info-content">
              <h4>Address</h4>
              <p>Jankpuri South,<br/> New Delhi, India, <br/>55060</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="contact-info-item">
            <div class="contact-info-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
            </div>
            
            <div class="contact-info-content">
              <h4>Phone</h4>
              <p>571-457-2321</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="contact-info-item">
            <div class="contact-info-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </div>
            
            <div class="contact-info-content">
              <h4>Email</h4>
              <p>support@shemade.com</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="contact-form">
          <form action="" id="contact-form">
            <h2>Send Message</h2>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" required="true" name="">
              <span>Full Name</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="email" required="true" name="">
              <span>Email</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="number" required="true" name="">
                <span>Contact No.</span>
              </div>
            
            <div class="input-box">
              <textarea required="true" name=""></textarea>
              <span>Type your Message...</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="submit" value="Send" name="">
            </div>
          </form>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  


{% endblock %}
```

I tried changing views, template syntax, many other things

Comment: Problem may be in urls.py or views.py.

Comment: Don't post images at outside stackoverflow. It's not very convenient. Just embed them with stackoverflow post question form. And Maybe post more information / code for Debugging the problem. urls.py, other related html pages may help.